# Why do visitors need to click on help button on discuss.Area51 to get back to the main proposal site?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, area-51, per-site-meta

I wonder if there is actually a good reason, why visitors of [*discuss.Area51*](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/) need to click on the "*help*" menu button first in order to get back to the [main Area51 site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/):

[image: link to main page discussion.Area51.SE]

In words, this seems to me more like "*I need Help, (how) do I return to the main page...?*" rather than "*Sent me (back) to the main page, (please).*"

This becomes even stranger when we look at the menu of the main page, since there is a direct link to the discussion site:

[image: link to discussion site on Area51.SE]

So what's the reason for this incongruity?

**Note:** As *@Shadow Wizard* mentioned this is the case in any StackExchange sites and its meta pages. On the other hand, discuss.Area51 is not the discussion site of Area51, but rather for its proposals.

Comment: This isn't just for Area 51, this is the case in any site and its meta. The Discussion Zone is the per-site meta of Area 51.

Comment: Yes you are right :) Should I edit my question or is there a similar post already?

Comment: No, the reverse is unique to Area 51 due to its... oldness. All other sites got a different UI, so this question is valid, and I doubt it was asked before. I was just explaining the tag I've added. :)